# Backdoor allows users without sufficient rep to create arbitrary tags by suggesting an edit on the Tag Wiki

Tags: discussion, bug, status-declined, tags, tag-wiki

I was reviewing Suggested TW edits when I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1888681).

- The [troubleshooting](/questions/tagged/troubleshooting) tag does not stand on its own.
- It hardly adds any meaning - virtually all questioners in Stack Overflow are trying to troubleshoot something!
- There are currently zero questions tagged with [troubleshooting](/questions/tagged/troubleshooting).

Also, I just noticed that the same user "created" 6 Tag Wikis that have either 0 or 1 tagged questions (check his [reputation history](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1316620/talles?tab=reputation) from today (April 9 2013)).

### How did these tags get there?

[image]

Comment: There are no questions tagged [tag:troubleshooting].  After 24 hours, the tag will self-destruct automatically.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Uhm interesting. Wasn't aware of that detail. One question though - how is the tag created without any question tagged with it? Was the original question edited having the tags edited?

Comment: Maybe it was created in response to the proposed tag wiki edit.  If you look in the lower left hand corner of the [suggested edit review](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1888681), you will see that Community created the tag at the same time that the user suggested the tag wiki edit.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Thanks for the info. `=]` Though, how can one propose a TW edit if the tag doesn't exist? For instance, I wanted to create a tag for one new library but apparently I cannot create a tag in any way other than asking a question with it. (Sorry for going off-topic, will open a support thread if necessary)

Comment: I wasn't aware that users could propose edits on a tag that doesn't exist; seems to me like a backdoor for users without sufficient rep to create new tags.

Comment: @RobertHarvey This means things may get more interesting then. Not sure if this is of help, but I've reviewed about 10 TW edits of that user in the last half hour.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I suspect the sequence of events was: 1. User 1 retags a question and creates [tag:troubleshooting]. 2. talles suggests the wiki. 3. User 2 retags the question and removes [tag:troubleshooting]. 4. Fabrício reviews the edit. I've been Fabrício before. It's always Community who creates the tag wiki and excerpt when someone submits content to it for the first time.

Comment: @Gilles That makes sense. Seems like I helped said [user](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1316620/talles?tab=reputation) to create 6 TWs that have either 0 or 1 questions asked *sigh*. My bad, but well, I'll stop approving such edits and let the diamond mods handle that I guess.

Comment: OK, I'm co-opting your question for a bug report.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I checked, and you're right, there's a bug (or at least behavior that is probably undesirable): you can submit a tag wiki for a tag that has 0 questions but hasn't been reaped by the daily cleaning job. [Example](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql-servre/info) — I just clicked on the tag's “edit” link which brought me to http://stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/90709 and let me submit.

Comment: @Gilles: Thanks for checking.

Comment: @RobertHarvey  This got a +1 from me before the bear, now I wish I could +1, 5 more times!

Comment: I don't think this is a bug. The only check is that the *tag exists* for creating tag wikis, so this would be more of a feature request to not allow tag wiki creations when there are 0 questions tagged under it. I agree,especially since the +2 reputation doesn't get reversed when tags get destroyed. Anyone could suggest bogus nonsense for random tags, garner the reputation, and then let it slip away into the twilight zone in a few hours.

Comment: @animuson Not only for the rep, but I believe this conduct is against the ethics which we should follow as SE users. Your suggestion looks like an acceptable solution (or at a good improvement to start off) imho. `=]`

Comment: @animuson: Works for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By looking in retrospect to this:

- Many of those tags ended up being niche, but valid tags and the edits were good.
- Some of them stopped being used.

I don't really see any problematic behavior or something that needs to be changed.